# Scapy Dot11 not found

Tags: python, pycharm, scapy

I can't seem to access Dot11. My setup is as follows:

1. Kali Linux VM image
2. Installed Scapy via: pip install git+https://github.com/secdev/scapy
3. Pycharm running python 3.6

The script:

```
from scapy.all import *

def packethandler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        print("hello")

sniff(iface="wlan0mon",prn=packethandler,store=0,monitor=True)
```

The Dot11 is flagged and is not found. However, I am able to do the following:

```
sniff(iface="wlan0mon", prn=lambda p: p.summary(), store=0)
```

which in turn actually works and finds 802.11 packets. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid using wildcard imports, try something like this:

```
from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11
from scapy.sendrecv import sniff

def packethandler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        print("hello")

sniff(iface="wlan0mon",prn=packethandler,store=0,monitor=True)
```